# Javascript - How to insert if and else statement inside option specification area of chart.js

Tags: javascript

I am using chart.js chart on my web page and I need to specify the min and max value of the chart axis. I can easily use the code shown below to specify the minimum and maximum value of the x axis of the chart but...

```
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                max: 100,
                min: 0,
```

But, I need to have different minimum and maximum value depending on the value of the javascript variable 'Subject'.

So, I need to have the code such as:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {

                if(Subject == 'English'){
                    return "max: 100,";
                } else {
                    return "max: 50,";
                }        
                min: 0
```

But this code shows "token not valid" error message. How can I correctly insert conditional statement within the javascript option specification area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) ?

```
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                max: (Subject == 'English') ? 100 : 50,
                min: 0,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the if statement outside the option, this worked for me:

```
if(Subject == 'English'){
  max1= 100;
} else {
  max1= 50;
}
```

And then:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                max: max1,
                min: 0,
```